# Selenium test works on production but not development

Tags: python, selenium, vue.js, selenium-chromedriver

I have a `Vue.js` app which I want to write selenium tests for. When I run a test against the deployed production version of the app the test passes but it fails when running it against a local version.

Of course when running locally the `Vue.js` app isn't running from a build but is instead running using `npm run serve`.

I have the following `docker compose` setup locally:

```yaml
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./app.dockerfile
    image: app
    command: npm run serve
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app

  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:91.0
    depends_on:
      - app

  e2e-tests:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./e2e_tests.dockerfile
    image: e2e-tests
    command: poetry run python ./foo.py
    depends_on:
      - app
      - selenium
    volumes:
      - ./e2e_tests:/app
```

Here's a basic test that works correctly using the `e2e-tests` and `selenium` container to test the deployed production version of the app out on the internet:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1420,1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://selenium:4444/wd/hub", options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.example.com')

try:
    assert 'My app title' in driver.title
except AssertionError:
    print('invalid title')

driver.quit()
```

If I now change the above test to use the `app` container which is simply a locally running version of the Vue app it fails because the title is empty:

```py
driver.get('http://app:8080')
```

I have tried adding a 10 second `wait` to the test after the `driver.get` but the title is still empty.

Comment: If you are on the machine where the test is running, and you open a browser pointing to http://app:8080, does the browser open the expected app?  and does the browser have a title?  Just check that the target url is actually working under the conditions that your script is trying to run under.

Comment: Yes If I go to http://localhost:8080 the website displays correctly on my laptop. The address http://app:8080 is used inside the containers, ie: `app` is the name of the docker compose service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the app was returning `Invalid Host Header` when selenium tried to call it from within docker even though I can access the app through a browser. Must be some docker related idiosyncrasy.

The solution was to update my `vue.config.js` as follows:

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true
  }
};
```

The `disableHostCheck` solved the issue. Apparently this should only be used while in dev as it would be a security risk if enabled in production.